# Procedure entry point_except1 could not be located in MSVCR120D.dll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to run a 2010 opencv C++ code (http://opencv-srf.blogspot.ca/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html) in Visual Studio 2012. I configured opencv, added all the dependencies (as mentioned at http://opencv-srf.blogspot.ca/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html), but I get the error "cannot open source file "SDKDDKVer.h"" - to solve this I changed the Platform Toolset in Configuration to Visual Studio 2012 (v110) from Visual Studio 2010 (v100). Finally the project was building without errors. But on run time it threw the error "missing MSVCP120D.dll" - I added the missing dlls manually (installing latest Visual C++ redistributable packages did not help) and now I am getting the error - "Procedure entry point_except1 could not be located in the dynamic link library MSVCR120D.dll"

What do I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. The opencv dependency was on the vc12 libs instead of vc11 which was causing the issue.